# Adding 750 rows into Datatables rows().add()

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am adding rows to a Datatable with the following code :

```
    for (var key in itm) {
      t.row.add([
        null,
        itm[key].itemcode,
        itm[key].itemdesc,
        itm[key].batch,
        itm[key].expiry,
        itm[key].qty,
        itm[key].unit,
        itm[key].rate,
        itm[key].total,
        itm[key].discper,
        itm[key].discamt,
        itm[key].staxper,
        itm[key].staxamt,
        itm[key].amount,
        itm[key].netprate,
        itm[key].salerate,
        itm[key].page,
        itm[key].sub1,
        itm[key].sub2,
        '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>',
        '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'
      ]).draw(false);
    }
```

This is working fine except for the large data.  When I try to add around 750 rows its too slow even the page hangs-up some times.

I tried to add the data using rows.add() API but its not working, the table is blank.  Here is the code i am using to add bulk data.

```
var t = $('#productTable').DataTable();
t.rows.add(itm);
```

My datatable definition is as under :

```
            $('#productTable').DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "searching": false,
                "info": false,
                "rowHeight": '100px',
                "scrollY":        "200px",
                "scrollX":        true,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging":         false,
                "columns": [
                    { data: null },
                    { data: 'itemcode' },
                    { data: 'itemdesc' },
                    { data: 'batch' },
                    { data: 'expiry' },
                    { data: 'qty' },
                    { data: 'unit' },
                    { data: 'rate' },
                    { data: 'total' },
                    { data: 'discper' },
                    { data: 'discamt' },
                    { data: 'staxper' },
                    { data: 'staxamt' },
                    { data: 'amount' },
                    { data: 'netprate' },
                    { data: 'salerate' },
                    { data: 'page' },
                    { data: 'sub1' },
                    { data: 'sub2' },
                    { data: null },
                    { data: null },],
              "columnDefs": [
                    { className: "dt-right", "targets": [7,8,9,10,11,12,13] },
                    { "targets": varbatchcol, visible: false },
                    { "targets": vardisccol, visible: false },
                    { "targets": vartaxcol, visible: false },
                    { "targets": vartotcol, visible: false },
                    { "targets": [17,18], visible: false },
                ],
                "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
                    $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
                    return nRow;
                }
            });
```

and the data coming from server is :

[image]

Comment: Why you are not using pagination?

Comment: In my special use case, I cannot use pagination.  I need to add data at client side.

Comment: it is obvously going to be slow if your data is that big and you have laptop ram less than 8 gig and slower processor. Use serverside datatables or use paginated data

Comment: Bulk adding using rows.add() will not solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
t.rows.add(itm);
should be
t.rows.add(itm).draw();

And this also solved the slow populating issue.